# Simultaneously writing several skew-symmetric matrices on a "canonical" form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symplectic-linear-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices

In a real finite vector space $V$ with a non-degenerated skew-symmetric form $\omega: V \to V$ there is always a so called *symplectic basis* $\{x_1,y_1, \cdots, x_n,x_n\},$ according to which $\omega$ is written as $$\omega = \sum_i dx^i\wedge dy^i,$$ or in other words, a basis such that $\omega(x_i,y_i) = 1$ for every $i$ and any other pairing vanishes. This is equivalent to saying that the matrix associated to $\omega$ in this basis has $1$'s above the diagonal, $-1$'s under it and zero everywhere else.

Now, if I have other non-degenerated skew-symmetric form $\widetilde\omega$, could I possibly find a basis for $V$ where the matrices of both $\omega$ and $\widetilde\omega$ are as described above, but with constants different than one? What I mean is, are there conditions for the skew symmetric forms that guarantee the existence of a basis $\{x_1,y_1, \cdots, x_n,x_n\}$ with respect to which one has $$\omega = \sum_i \alpha_idx^i\wedge dy^i$$ $$\widetilde\omega = \sum_i \widetilde\alpha_idx^i\wedge dy^i,$$ so that they are simultaneously written on a "canonical" simpler way?

The usual construction of a symplectic basis for a skew-symmetric form doesn't seem to apply in this situation because despite being able to construct a two-dimensional subspace $W \subset V$ that is symplectic with respect to both $\omega$ and $\widetilde\omega$ we have no control over what happen to the intersection of their orthogonal complements $W^\omega$ and $W^{\widetilde\omega}$ in order to try an induction argument, which makes me think such a basis should not *always* exist.

I'm looking into the case where there are two forms involved to get an idea of what can happen, but I'm actually more interested in the situation where one has a finite number $k$ of skew-symmetric forms involved.